# Nombrar un objeto con el contenido de una variable en Python

Tags: python-3.x, poo

los pongo en contexto: Estoy haciendo un sistema de registro en el que cada usuario es un objeto. Aquí la clase:

```
class User:
def __init__(self, nombre, apellido, nick, gen, mail, contra):
    self.nombre = nombre
    self.apellido = apellido
    self.nick = nick
    self.gen = gen
    self.mail = mail
    self.contra = contra
```

Bueno, aqui mi duda: Quiero saber si es posible, y si lo es de que manera, crear un objeto cuyo nombre sea el contenido de una variable.
Tengo una variable que se llama nick, que mediante un input guarda el nickname del usuario, y quiero que el nombre del objeto (el usuario) sea el contenido de esta.
Por ejemplo, si nick = "Artur", crear un objeto `User` cuyo nombre sea artur.
Perdón si es un lio la pregunta, pero estoy aprendiendo Python de manera autodidacta y no encuentro informacion sobre este tema en ningun lado.

Desde ya gracias :D

Comment: Te refieres a instanciar un `User()` pasándole `"Arthur"` como nombre? Eso sería simplemente pasarle la variable `nick` como primer parámetro al constructor. Sospecho que no es esto lo que preguntas. ¿Será entonces que quieres crear una variable llamada `Arthur`, como si hubieras hecho `Arthur = User(...)`, pero siendo el nombre de la variable tomado de otra (`nick`)? Eso puede hacerse pero es muy retorcido y mala práctica. ¿Podrías explicar por qué lo necesitas? Parece un problema XY.

Comment: Voy al grano: Si instanciara User() de manera manual seria Arthur = User(parametros), pero quiero que lo haga de manera automática. Si nick = "Arthur" quiero que se instancie así: Arthur = User(), y si nick = "Pepe" quiero que se instancie asi: Pepe = User(). Es realmente posible hacerlo?

Comment: Sí, te entiendo. Es por tanto la segunda opción de las que enuncié. Es posible, pero no recomendable, pues ¿cómo accederías después a esa variable? (tendría que ser de nuevo a través del nombre de otra). Si explicas para qué necesitas eso, podría darte la mejor forma de resolverlo (que posiblemente será usar un diccionario)

Comment: Lo necesito para un sistema de registro de usuarios, para acceder mas facilmente a los objetos pensé que era buena idea usar un nickname que el usuario elija para instanciar el objeto. Si es demasiado dificil o no tiene solución acepto cualquier otra recomendación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que preguntas es cómo tener una variable que se llame por ejemplo `arthur`, es decir, conseguir el equivalente a:

```
arthur = User()
```

pero dejando que el usuario elija el nombre de la variable, es decir con algo como:

```
nick = input("Cómo quieres que se llame la variable?" )

# Magia para crear una variable llamada como haya respondido el usuario
```

La verdadera pregunta es ¿por qué querrías algo así? ¿Por qué el usuario habría de poder elegir el nombre de la variable si al final esa variable el usuario no la verá nunca? (lo que verá son los datos, pero no los nombres de las variables).

Sólo sirve para complicarte la vida como programador, pues supongamos que la línea esa con "Magia" hace lo que tu quieres. Tendrás entonces una variable que no sabes cómo se llama, pues el nombre lo eligió el usuario. ¿Y qué haces ahora con ella?

Imagina que quieres imprimir el apellido de ese `User()`. Si la variable se llama `arthur`, podrías `print(arthur.nombre)`, pero como no sabes cómo se llama la variable ¿qué pones en el `print()`?

Dicho lo anterior, lo más parecido a lo que buscas sería tener un diccionario cuyas claves sean los "nicks" y cuyos valores sean los objetos `User()` que vas creando. Por ejemplo, algo como esto:

```
usuarios = {}  # Diccionario inicialmente vacío

# Crear un usuario
nick = input("Dame el nick: ")

# Lectura del resto de datos del usuario
nombre = input("Nombre: ")
apellido = input("Apellido: ")
# ... etc

# Creación del objeto e inserción en el diccionario
usuarios[nick] = User(nombre, apellido, ...)
```

Ahora, para acceder a los datos de un usuario cualquiera, dado su nick, basta que hagas `usuarios[nick]` y tendrás el objeto `User` correspondiente. Por ejemplo:

```
print("Vamos a ver el apellido de un usuario")
nick = input("Dame su nick: ")
if nick not in usuarios:
    print("Ese nick no se encuentra")
else:
    print("El apellido de {} es {}".format(nick, usuarios[nick].apellido))
```

Creo que con esto tienes la funcionalidad deseada. Si insistes en tener variables independientes que se llamen como el usuario elija, puede hacerse (pista: usando `globals()` o `locals()` que son diccionarios creados por python para contener todas las variables del programa, globales y locales respectivamente). Pero sería código feo y antipytónico, y no le veo el sentido.

Comment: Es exactamente lo que necesitaba. Gracias :D